# myorigin Setting for Virtual Mailboxes

Tags: postfix, email

To support more domain names and non-system accounts we have recently reconfigured postfix to use virtual domains.

For receiving mail this is working well but when mail is sent it is often marked as spam by receiving mail servers because the mail is marked as coming from 'localhost' rather than the real host/domain name as it was prior to the change to virtual domains.

In main.cf these lines are set:

```
myhostname = mail.example.com
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $mydomain
+ other settings for virtual domains
mydestination is commented out as all domains are virtual.
```

These seem to make no difference to the sending domain.

Ideally mail should be marked as coming from 'mail.example.com' or 'mail.example2.com' depending on the sending domain. If that is not possible then marking it as coming from anything other than 'localhost' would be fine. Could anyone point out the settings that are missing or wrong please?

**EDIT** In the received email the 'return path' is correct, 'localhost' occurs in the line:

Received: from localhost ([a.b.c.d]) by mail.receivingserver.com

Comment: What is sending the mails?

Comment: It is a standard postfix/dovecot setup

Comment: No, I mean what is the mail client which is submitting these mails to Postfix to be sent.

Comment: Various clients, including Mac Mail and Outlook. Postfix is also invoked by several programs to send reports etc.

Comment: are you sure your problem is myorigin? is 'localhost' in the From header or somewhere else? sounds more like broken rDNS or wrong HELO.

Comment: @Gryphus I do not know if the problem is specifically with myorigin, maybe there is something I need to add to DNS but when the system was set up just to use a single 'real' domain it worked fine. I have updated the question with details of where localhost occurs.

Comment: does 'postconf myhostname' really return 'mail.example.com' ? "Received from localhost" sounds like your HELO is wrong, but according to your description it is set correctly. Does the rDNS PTR for your IP return 'mail.example.com' as well?

Comment: @Gryphius The details in the question are from /etc/postfix/main.cf. 'postconf myhostname' returns 'myhostname = localhost'. The rDNS record is set to mail.example.com and Rackspace support have confirmed that this is working correctly.

Comment: did you run 'postfix reload' after changing myhostname in main.cf? if not, try it and then run 'postconf myhostname' again and check if it returns the correct hostname now.

Answer (score 1):

> Received: from localhost

sounds like your smtp HELO is not configured correctly. from your description you have set the [myhostname](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myhostname) parameter in main.cf , but didn't reload postfix after that

try running `postfix reload` and confirm with `postconf myhostname`. If this doesn't return *mail.example.com* now you are probably editing the wrong main.cf. in that case run `postconf -e 'myhostname = mail.example.com'` and `postfix reload`